# How to list and count each attribute in R?

Tags: r, count

I have a list of service like below. How to list all the different services and the number of time each service occurred? I would like to do it in R

Thank you very much

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(postprod = c("a, b, c", "b, c, d"))
df %>% 
  separate_rows(postprod) %>% 
  count(postprod)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   postprod     n
#> * <chr>    <int>
#> 1 a            1
#> 2 b            2
#> 3 c            2
#> 4 d            1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

using **data.table**

```r
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(postprod = c("a, b, c", "b, c, d"))
setDT(df)[, list(postprod = unlist(tstrsplit(postprod, split = ", ")))][, .N, by = postprod]
#>    postprod N
#> 1:        a 1
#> 2:        b 2
#> 3:        c 2
#> 4:        d 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>